# How to mock a function within a Function. Is it possible to use two or more Patches to mock a function call within a Function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, function-call

I need to mock a Function (funk) call that is dependent on the return values of two other functions that is called within this Function (funk). Is it possible to use more than 1 Patch to mock the return value of the two called functions.

API to be Tested/ Mocked:

```
from subprocess import check_output


def get_value_a(value_a: int):  
    return value_a  

def get_value_b(value_b: int):  
    return value_b  

def print_contents_of_cwd(val_a, val_b):  
    if val_a > 0:  
        return check_output(['ls']).split()  
    else:  
        return val_b
```

I am trying to use two patches to mock the return value of both the functions (`get_value_a` and `get_value_b`) as below:

```
from Mack_Test_Practise import list_dir
from unittest import mock, TestCase


class TestExamples(TestCase):
    # Using Decorator Method

    @mock.patch('Mack_Test_Practise.list_dir.check_output',
                return_value=b'list_dir.py')
    @mock.patch('Mack_Test_Practise.list_dir.get_value_a',
                return_value=5)
    @mock.patch('Mack_Test_Practise.list_dir.get_value_b',
                return_value=3)
    def test_print_contents_of_file(self, mock_check_output,val_a, val_b):
        actual_result = list_dir.print_contents_of_cwd(val_a, val_b)
        print("actual_result", actual_result)

        expected_result = b'list_dir.py'
        self.assertIn(expected_result, actual_result)
```

When I run the test the following error is thrown.

```
Error  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1183, in patched  
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File  
 "/home/shyam/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Mock_Test/test_list_dir.py", line 15, in test_print_contents_of_file
    actual_result = list_dir.print_contents_of_cwd(val_a, val_b)
  File "/home/shyam/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Mack_Test_Practise/list_dir.py", line 13, in print_contents_of_cwd  
    if val_a > 0:  
**TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'**
```

My first question is, is it allowed to use multiple patches like I did ?
My Second question is why do we get the Type Error since it is a legal operator in Python.
Please suggest a solution.

Thanks a million and Best Regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is legal to use multiple patches like this.

I think your issue is because you have patched a function, and are trying to compare the patched function to an integer. You set the return value in the mock, but you still need to call it to get that return value.

```
actual_result = list_dir.print_contents_of_cwd(val_a(), val_b())
```

Note the included parentheses on `val_a()` and `val_b()`

Now, since these are no longer values, but rather functions (technically, they are MagicMock objects, but they are replacing functions) I would suggest renaming them to `get_val_a()` and `get_val_b()` so that your intent is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. For future reference it is usually better to wait a day or so so that other users (possibly in different time zones) are not discouraged from providing answers as well.

Comment: One last question, Is it possible to mock a private function ? like __download_file ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html and search for "mangling" for info on how python changes method names with leading double underscore.

Comment: That said. Needing to mess about with private variables/methods is usually an antipattern. Consider whether it might be better to refactor your code, or redesign it in such a way that accessing privates is not necessary. (I understand that it is just for testing, but even still, there is usually a better way.)